# Plot of $n$ concentric circles at once?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

While we plot the Equation of $$(x^2+y^2-1)=0$$ we get:

[image: 1]

While we plot $$(x^2+y^2-4)=0$$ we get:

[image: 2]

So What will happen if we plot

> $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{i=n} \Big({(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-i^2}\Big)=0$$

??

Will we get *Concentric Circles*?

[image: 3]

*Also...WolframAlpha agrees! ([Link of concentric circles with radii=1,2,3](http://goo.gl/USKUhi))*

---

> Also if not...What will be the Cartesian/polar equation of concentric circles?

Comment: Don't you mean $-i^2$ in your third equation, and not $-n^2$ ... ? PS great question !

Comment: @pbs Oh sorry...fixed!

Comment: $\sin(\pi r/R)=\sin(\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/R)=0$ gives you an infinity of concentric circles of radii $nR$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Wow! Thanks a lot! ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

If $\hspace{0.25cm}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n a_k = 0\hspace{0.25cm}$ then for some $K$, $a_K = 0$.

Now let $a_k = (x^2+y^2 - k^2)$... what can you conclude?